# Python: Rotate mxn array to an arbitrary angle

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-algebra

I have matrix filled with zeros and a rectangle filled by ones on a region of this matrix, like this

[image]

and I want to rotate the rectangle to an arbitrary angle (30° in this case) like this

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_x = 200
n_y = 200
data = np.zeros((n_x, n_y))
data[20:50, 20:40] = 1

plt.imshow(data)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using scipy?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import  rotate

n_x = 200
n_y = 200
data = np.zeros((n_x, n_y))
data[20:50, 20:40] = 1

angle = 30
data = rotate(data, angle) 

plt.imshow(data)

plt.show()
```

Of course this is around the middle of the image. If you want to rotate around the center of the rectangle, I would suggest translating it to the middle of the image, rotate it and then translate it back.

Answer (score 1):

From a mathematical point of view you could solve the problem by transforming 
the cartesian coordinates of the ones into polar coordinates relative to the center of the rectangle.

```
r = sqrt(x²+y²)
phi = atan2(y,x)
```

(Note that x and y have to be relative to the center of rotation)
With polar coordinates it is no problem to rotate, since you just have to add the desired angle to phi and than transform back into cartesian coordinates.

```
x = r*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(phi)
```

(And again, the resulting coordinates would be with respect to the center of rotation, so you need to add them to the cartesian vector which points to the center)